# how a right angle triangle and an equilateral triangle homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

I know that a right angle triangle abd an equilateral triangle is homeomorphic in euclidean plane with usual topology I am unable to find an explicit homeomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a point within a triangle, project the triangle onto a circumscribed circle.
Show that is a homeomorphism between the trangle and the circle.
Do the same with the other triangle.

Comment: yes this is okbut can I get an explisit mapbetween two triangles

Answer (score 0):

If you have two triangles $OAB$ and $O A^\prime B^\prime$ in $\Bbb R^2$ with $O$ the origin, you can take the homeomorphism to be the only linear map taking $\overrightarrow{OA}$ to $\overrightarrow{OA^\prime}$ and $\overrightarrow{OB}$ to $\overrightarrow{OB^\prime}$. This gives you an explicit homeomorphism as long as the triangles are explicit.